# Localization without calculus of fractions

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, examples-counterexamples, localization

I'm studying the localization functor that makes morphism in $\Sigma$ invertible, where $\Sigma$ is class of morphism in a category (the Gabriel-Zisman localization).

It is known that if $\Sigma$ admits a right calculus fraction, then the localization functor preserves finite limits (see, for example, Proposition 5.2.5 of Borceux - Handbook of Categorical Algebra - Vol. 1).

I'm trying to find a study on properties of the localization when $\Sigma$ does not admit a right calculus fraction. Would you have any references?
I'm in a situation where $\Sigma$ may admit some kind of weaker right calculus fraction, and I hope this will give that the localization preserves some finite limits, but not all.
If you could share an example of localization that behaves like this, I would appreciate it.

Comment: As it stands, you're just asking for essentially any research on localizations. It's too broad. You'd do better to tell us exactly the kind of localization you're looking at, and maybe somebody can find a reference dealing with such localizations (although this is pretty likely to be a better fit for MO.)

Comment: @KevinArlin Ok, thanks! I assumed that would be specific references of localization-like functors that preserve only equalizers, for example. Since this question is too broad, I will elaborate and repost in MO.